# Adding to List replaces previous elements

Tags: c#, list, windows-8

I have a list that is used as a DataContext in a GridView.

This list is created with the following code:

```
        private void initializeStarredHub()
    {
        List<StarredData> starredList = new List<StarredData>();
        starredList.Add(new StarredData("ms-appx:///Images/Absence.png", "Sample Data 1"));
        starredList.Add(new StarredData("ms-appx:///Images/Absence.png", "Sample Data 2"));
        StarredHub.DataContext = starredList;
    }
```

Where StarredData is

```
    public class StarredData
    {
        public static string StarredImage { get; set; }
        public static string StarredTitle { get; set; }

        public StarredData() { }

        public StarredData(string itemImageSet, string itemNameSet)
        {
            StarredImage = itemImageSet;
            StarredTitle = itemNameSet;
        }
    }
```

The end result of the above is both starredList[0] and starredList[1] have "Sample Data 2" as the StarredTitle, meaning all previous values are overwritten by the latest set.

Why is this happening and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you declared `static` members in `StarredData` class, just remove the `static` keywords:

```
public class StarredData
{
    public string StarredImage { get; set; }
    public string StarredTitle { get; set; }

    public StarredData() { }

    public StarredData(string itemImageSet, string itemNameSet)
    {
        StarredImage = itemImageSet;
        StarredTitle = itemNameSet;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can fix it by removing the `static` keyword from your member definition.

> Only one copy of a static member exists, regardless of how many instances of the class are created.

Check here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3.aspx